# How to remotely backup a MySQL database?

Tags: backup, mysql, rsync, database

How to backup MySQL database in a remote location using `rsync`?

I tried `mysqldump` but it is storing the backup in the local machine only. Also I need the backup files to be stored in tar format in the remote location.

Is there any way to combine `rsync` and `mysqldump` to store the backup in a remote system in tar format?

Comment: Install mysql-client on the remote machine and run `mysqldump` from there. `tar` the file after dumping. Does it help?

Comment: @EricCarvalho Instead of dumping and then creating tar file, how can i backup sql in  tar format itself

Comment: The dump generates one file. Do you want to add it to an existing tar file or just compress it?

Comment: @EricCarvalho i want to compress the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar` cannot create an archive with data received from standard input, so you must first dump the database and then `tar` it. To save space you can compress the dumped data on the fly.

Install mysql-client (`apt-get install mysql-client`) on the remote machine and run `mysqldump` from there:

```
mysqldump -h <server-hostname-or-ip-address> <options> <database-names> | bzip2 > dump-`date +%F-%H%M`.bz2
```

If you really need a tar archive, `tar` the bziped file:

```
tar cf <archive-name>.tar <bziped-dump>.bz2
```

or add it to an existent archive:

```
tar rf <pre-existent-archive-name>.tar <bziped-dump>.bz2
```